# Who did Qui-gon train before Obi-wan?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, jedi-training

Who did Qui-gon Jinn train before Obi-wan? How did he become a Master?

Comment: I don't see what improvement your last edit made. If anything, it slightly damaged it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Comic Series "[Star Wars : Jedi - The Dark Side I](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Jedi%E2%80%94The_Dark_Side_1)", Qui-Gon's first apprentice was a human male called [Feemor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Feemor).

[image]

When Feemor became a Jedi Knight, Qui-gon was immediately elevated to the rank of Master.

---

The old (and now defunct) [article on Qui-Gon](http://web.archive.org/web/20110911225304/http://www.starwars.com/databank/character/quigonjinn/index.html) from the Star Wars Databank explains an apparent discrepancy in some of the earlier EU novels:

> Though Qui-Gon defeated Xanatos, he could not bear to kill his own
>   Padawan. The defeated student fled and Qui-Gon obsessed over his
>   failure for years, **dismissing his earlier successes as a teacher and
>   often referring to [Xanatos](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Xanatos) as his "first" apprentice.**

Comment: Perhaps Feemor was his first actual apprentice, and after he became a Master he trained Xanatos & failed? IIRC Xanatos was the padawan right before Kenobi. The pair had to fight Xanatos in one of the young adult books.

Comment: @Omegacron - Yes, that's exactly right. There's a discrepancy between two of the earlier novels that this article is attempting (poorly) to mend.